# ckeditor5 deletes my attribute.. which method should I use?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using ckeditor5.
When uploading an image, a custom attribute was added using a custom adapter.
However, if the content changes, the custom attribute is deleted. Is there no way?

I tried various searches, but couldn't find the right way.

The code below is for me to add a custom attribute.

```js
export const attrPlugin = (editor: any): void => {
  editor.plugins
    .get("ImageUploadEditing")
    .on("uploadComplete", (evt: any, { data, imageElement }) => {
      editor.model.change((writer: any) => {
        writer.setAttribute("tmpFid", data.tmpFid, imageElement);
      });
      const nd = editor.model.schema.extend("imageBlock", {
        allowAttributes: "tmpFid",
      });
      editor.model.schema.extend("imageInline", {
        allowAttributes: "tmpFid",
      });
      const thd = editor.conversion.for("upcast").attributeToAttribute({
        view: "tmp-fid",
        model: "tmpFid",
      });
      editor.conversion.for("editingDowncast").add((dispatcher: any) => {
        dispatcher.on(
          "attribute:tmpFid:imageInline",
          (evt: any, data: any, { writer, consumable, mapper }) => {
            if (!consumable.consume(data.item, evt.name)) {
              return;
            }
            const imageContainer = mapper.toViewElement(data.item);
            const imageElement = imageContainer.getChild(0);
            if (data.attributeNewValue !== null) {
              writer.setAttribute(
                "tmp-fid",
                data.attributeNewValue,
                imageElement
              );
            } else {
              writer.removeAttribute("tmp-fid", imageElement);
            }
          }
        );
      });
      editor.conversion.for("downcast").add((dispatcher: any) => {
        dispatcher.on(
          "attribute:tmpFid:imageBlock",
          (evt: any, data: any, conversionApi: any) => {
            if (!conversionApi.consumable.consume(data.item, evt.name)) {
              return;
            }
            const viewWriter = conversionApi.writer;
            const figure = conversionApi.mapper.toViewElement(data.item);
            const img = figure.getChild(0);
            if (data.attributeNewValue !== null) {
              viewWriter.setAttribute("tmp-fid", data.attributeNewValue, img);
            } else {
              viewWriter.removeAttribute("tmp-fid", img);
            }
          }
        );
      });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the schema of the editor on creation (maybe later) like this, I am altering for a paragraph element to hold "class","style" and my other attributes (using jQuery and mvc-razor but should be same on all frameworks):

```
CKSource.Editor
.create(document.querySelector('#' + divId),
    {
        toolbar: {
            items: [
                blabla
            ]
        }
    })
.then(newEditor => {

    var editor = newEditor;

    @* editor will alter class etc if you want to add them, so give permission to some atributes here*@
    editor.model.schema.extend( 'paragraph', { allowAttributes: [ 'class','data-operation','data-id','style' ] } );
    editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute({ model: 'class', view: 'class' });
    editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute({ model: 'data-operation', view: 'data-operation' });
    editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute({ model: 'data-id', view: 'data-id' });
    editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute({ model: 'style', view: 'style' } );
```